# How to use ScalikeJDBC's returning() with a where clause

Tags: scala, scalikejdbc

I am trying to use Postgres' `RETURNING` with ScalikeJDBC (see https://github.com/scalikejdbc/scalikejdbc/issues/559)

How is this suppose to work with a `where` clause. The `returning(...)` is a member of `UpdateSQLBuilder`, whereas a `where` returns a `ConditionSQLBuilder`

```scala
update(Post)
   .set(sqls"${p.views}=${p.views}+${newViews}")
   .where.eq(p.id,id)
   .returning(p.id,p.lastUpdated, p.views) // does not work as it is not a member of ConditionSQLBuilder
```

Answer (score 5):

As you said, `returning` is not a member of `ConditionSQLBuilder`. However, you can use `append` method after your `where` clause, since it is defined on `ConditionSQLBuilder`:

```
update(Post)
   .set(sqls"${p.views} = ${p.views} + ${newViews}")
   .where.eq(p.id, id)
   .append(sqls"returning ${p.id}, ${p.lastUpdated}, ${p.views}"
```

And, if you will map returning columns into an object using your builder like this:

```
val postOpt = withSQL(builder).map(Post(p)).single().apply()
```

Then you must use `${p.result.columnName}` instead of `${p.columnName}` in your `SQLSyntax`, which you passed to `append` method as a parameter. To map all columns, simply use `${p.result.*}`.